# How to Upgrade/Downgrade Rubygems version in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, upgrade

I need to downgrade the rubygem version from 1.8.24 to 1.4.2 in Heroku.

I tried the following commands to downgrade it. But when cross checked it still shows 1.8.24.

$ heroku run rvm install rubygems 1.4.2
$ heroku run gem update --system 1.4.2

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that You can run `gem update --system` on heroku :).

> Heroku does not provide permanent disk space, the gem files
>   uploaded onto gem server are lost after application redeploy. It is
>   especially bad because Heroku shuts your application down if it's been
>   idle for more than 1 hour.

Comment: Ok. Is there any other way I can use the downgrade version of rubygems?

Comment: Try use official guide https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/UPGRADING.rdoc